# How does Kafka handle topics and partitions with jbod storage type?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have Kafka brokers using jbod storage types

```
storage:
  type: jbod
  volumes:
  - id: 0
    type: persistent-claim
    size: 50Gi
    deleteClaim: false
  - id: 1
    type: persistent-claim
    size: 50Gi
    deleteClaim: false
  - id: 2
    type: persistent-claim
    size: 50Gi
    deleteClaim: false
```

I see that Kafka sees each disk as a different folder and

```
/dev/nvme2n1 on /var/lib/kafka/data-2 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/nvme5n1 on /var/lib/kafka/data-0 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/nvme4n1 on /var/lib/kafka/data-1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

It will distribute topics/partitions across different disks, for example, partition 9 of topic my-nice-topic will be stored in disk 0

```
var/lib/kafka/data-0/kafka-log70/my-nice-topic-9
```

Now, my doubt is what happens in disk 0 gets full and the other 2 no? I'm not looking for a response that I should reassign partitions better, my question is oriented to this:

If disk 0 gets full, will I lose partition 9 data for topic my-nice-topic? Will it continue storing files in another disk for partition 9?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a partition is created in Kafka, it will be assigned to one of the volumes. This is done without considering the partition sizes or disk capacity too much. And even for existing partitions, Kafka itself will not do any balancing between the volumes.

So it can easily happen that the volumes are not in balance - one might be getting full while the other might be half empty. And when the disk gets full, you will have a problem since Kafka will not start using the other disks. That said, the disk getting full does not necessarily mean you lose all your data. It just means no new messages can be accepted.

There are several ways how you can prevent it from happening:

- If possible, set the retention limits so that the disk cannot get full even when the partitions are at their max size.
- Use tools such as Cruise Control to *rebalance* the cluster. It can optimize the way the volumes are used by reshuffling the partitions between them.
- Use one bigger volume instead of 3 small volumes. Using multiple volumes is not always the best choice - so make sure you have valid reasons why are you using it. Some of the pros and cons are covered in this [video](https://youtu.be/7gaOUjkuR68).
- Use monitoring and alerting to avoid the disks getting full.

Comment: Thank you, really complete response.